# JSessionId changes after login and Angular 5 is sending new JSessionID with request and discarding the old jsessionid

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-mvc, session-management

I am new to Angular 5 and Spring MVC and I am trying to create the login functionality for my application.

We are not using Spring Security as we are only using basic session management provided by the Spring MVC module.

I am saving the `JsessionId` (say `LoginSessionId`) in my front end generated by the `LoginController` when trying to authenticate my user after sending the first request to backend:

[image: Basic Session Creation in spring MVC]

I am sending the same `LoginSessionId` with each request in 'Authorization' header with the help of `HttpInterceptor`:

[image: HttpInterceptor]

But after login, Angular 5 is sending a new `JsessionId` in the Cookie and discarding the previously returned `JsessionId` from the cookie in response of first request.

In my backend (Spring MVC) a new `Sessionid` gets generated from second request onwards and previously generated `SessionId` (`LoginSessionId`) gets discarded.

[image: Screenshot of multiple HttpSessions]

I want to save and use the `LoginSessionId` in my backend operations.

Kindly guide me how to do that? I am using Apache Tomcat 8.0.43 and Spring MVC version 5.0.4.  I have already enabled CORS Headers. Kindly let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: Please don't add text as images

Comment: @JamesZ Thank you. Will take care of that from now on.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the issue. I was not adding header `withCredentials` in the first request. So my backend server was identifying `JsessionId` only from second request onwards.